# Show that a particular projection is a linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

After one year without really touching the concepts of linear algebra, I need to do it because I started a new course on computational science, where apparently linear algebra is essential.

I don't remember exactly what's a projection, but I've an exercise where I need to show that the projection $L: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as follows $$L\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$$ is a linear mapping.

As far as I understood, after revising a little bit about linear mappings, to show that a mapping $L$ is linear we basically need to show it has two properties:

1. $L(v_1 + v_2) = L(v_1) + L(v_2)$, for $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the subspace domain of $L$, in my case $\mathbb{R}^3$.
2. $L(c \cdot v_1) = c L(v_1)$, for some $v_1$ in the subspace domain of $L$ and some scalar $c$.

I tried to apply these definitions to try to solve my problem as follows. First I tried to show that the first condition holds.

$$L\left(\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix}\right) = L\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix} + L\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Starting from the left side of $=$ sign, we know, according to the basic vector algebra's rules that:

$$L\begin{pmatrix} v_1 + u_1 \\ v_2 + u_2 \\ v_3 + u_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

We can now apply the definition of $L$ and we obtain

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ v_2 + u_2 \\ v_3 + u_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

If we now proceed from the right-hand side of the $=$ sign, we know
 that

$$L\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix} + L\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ v_2 + u_2 \\ v_3 + u_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

which is exactly what we have found starting from the right-hand side.

I did similar manipulations for the second condition.

My question is: does this procedure prove that $L$ is a linear mapping? If not, why? And how would I prove $L$ is a linear map then?

Comment: Yes you proved it. It's that straightforward.

Comment: Right, $L^2$ means $L\circ L$: $L^2(x) = L(L(x))$.  $L^2 = L$  $L$ means that $L$ is the identity on its image (leaves everything in its image unchanged). Note that if $L$ is a linear map then its image is a linear subspace the range space is. E.g. the set of all $(0,y,z)$ in $\Bbb R^3$ is a (2-dimensional) subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: That's right. This $L$ has a nice simple definition in terms of the standard basis vectors $(1,0,0), (01,0), (0,0,1)$. In general, a projection will have the same nice property for some (indeed, any) basis of its image, but of course not necessarily in terms of the standard basis. E.g., if you project onto a "slanted" plane in $\Bbb R^3$, then a basis for that plane won't have all 0's in one of the 3 coordinates (*in terms of the standard basis*).  <cont>

Comment: <cont> But: take any non-$0$ vector on an line orthogonal to the plane; that, together with the two vectors of the plane's basis, give a basis for $\Bbb R^3$. The projection sends that line to 0, and leaves the plane unchanged. So it really is "the same thing".

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it shed some light on the topic.